# how can i make a request in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i just my training job on an application that was developed by other company, and there is not comment on the apps and this is my first time i start to use the `Laravel` Framework, so i need to make a filter to look for the customers that they already subscribe on the apps, and i don't know how can i make the request on the apps and where i can show the result?
thanks a lot guys for advance.

this is the function i found on the apps

```
public function ajaxsearch(Request $request){




 $client = $request->get('client',null) ;
 $date_depart = $request->get('date_depart',null) ;
 $date_arrivee = $request->get('date_arrivee',null) ;
 $chauffeur = $request->get('chauffeur',null) ;
 $status = $request->get('status',null) ;
 $query = Course::where('id','!=',0);
```

i add this variable to use the same function to add a search bar on the apps 
     //$client_filter = $request->get('client',null);

```
// chercher for the customers from the Courses table
if($client){
   $courses = $query->Where('client_id', 'like', '%' . $client . '%');

}
// to search for customers they already have a courses with all information date time and adress of start and arrive on the filter i wanna to add
/*if($client_filter){
  $projets = $query->Where('client_id', '=' , $client . '%');
}
*/

if($date_depart){
   $courses = $query->Where('date_depart', 'like', '%' . $date_depart . '%');

}
if($date_arrivee){
   $courses = $query->Where('date_arrivee', 'like', '%' . $date_arrivee . '%');

}
if($chauffeur){
   $courses = $query->Where('user_id', 'like', '%' . $chauffeur . '%');

}
if($status){
   $courses = $query->Where('status', 'like', '%' . $status . '%');

}

// for the view of the customer
$courses = $query->where('id' -> input::get('client_id'),'nom_usage' -> input::get('nom_usage'))->get();
return view($this->views.'.search',compact('Courses'));


$courses = $query->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    return view($this->views.'.search',compact('courses'));

}
```

Comment: you mean i have to create a new function ?

Answer (score 0):

if you some condition from your request , you should use this structure :

```
$query = YourModel::query();

if ($request->filled('condition_1')){
    $query->where('col_1','operator',$request->condition_1);
}


if ($request->filled('condition_2')){
    $query->where('col_2','operator',$request->condition_2);
}

$objects = $query->latest()->paginate()->appends($request->query());

// return view ...
```

with this structure you can use many condition in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kinda hard to understand, but I will try to help. Use [Conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses) in your controller to build your query, for example:

```
$courses = DB::table('courses')
    ->when($request->filled('client'), function ($query) {
        return $query->where('client_id', $request->client);
    })
    ->get();
```

Then pass this data to a view:

```
return view('courses.index')->with(['courses' => $courses]);
```

Then in your view `courses/index.blade.php` output your data:

```
@foreach ($courses as $course)
    {{ $course->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: that's work but i don't get the result i'm looking for.
thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: What’s the point then? If we understand your question we may help you to get the result you want. ;)